# How to resolve console application exited with code 9009

Tags: c#, wpf, console-application, exec

Im try to run a c# console application in build process by using below command

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).$(OutputType)" />
  </Target>
```

Error when Build : error exited with code 9009

Note : This error occurs due to my project have space in  parent folders

this same scenario working fine when parent folder name does not have space

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: It looks like the error code is a file/folder not found and usually occurs with a SQL Server.  Make sure you have either the full path to the file or a relative path that starts with respect to the c# executable.

Comment: @jdweng this same scenario working fine when parent folder name does not have space

Comment: The you need single quotes around the path.

Comment: @jdweng Can you please explain?

Comment: "'$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).$(OutputType)'"

Comment: @jdweng you suggestion cause another error "exited with code 123"

Comment: What does the command string look like after al the parameters are added?  It should look like mycommand 'abc\def ghi\xyz.exe'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222590/discussion-between-max-and-jdweng).

Comment: Hi @jdweng

please find  exact error line

project generator\ProjectGeneratorApp\bin\Release-Xml\ProjectGeneratorApp.Exe'" exited with code 123.

Comment: Why is there a double quote at end of string?